# C# text creation issue

Tags: c#

This is whats going on.   I have a huge text file that is suppose to be 1 line per entry.  The issue is sometimes the line is broken with a new line.

I edit this entire file and wherever the file doesn't begin with ("\"A) i need to append the current line to the previous line ( replacing \n with " ").  Everything I come up with keeps appending the line to a new line.  Any help is appricated...

CODE:

```
    public void step1a()  
    {
        string begins = ("\"A");
        string betaFilePath = @"C:\ext.txt";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(betaFilePath);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(begins))
            {
             File.AppendAllText(@"C:\xt2.txt",line);
             File.AppendAllText(@"C:\xt2.txt", "\n");
            }
            else
            {
            string line2 = line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\xt2.txt",line2);
            }

        }

    }
```

Example:
Orig:
"\"A"Hero|apple|orange|for the fun of this
"\"A"Hero|apple|mango|lots of fun always
"\"A"Her|apple|fruit|no
pain is the way
"\"A"Hero|love|stackoverflowpeople|more fun

Resulting:
"\"A"Hero|apple|orange|for the fun of this
"\"A"Hero|apple|mango|lots of fun always
"\"A"Her|apple|fruit|no pain is the way
"\"A"Hero|love|stackoverflowpeople|more fun

my problem isnt the finding the if (line.StartsWith(begins)) its the else statement, it appends line2 to a new line

Comment: I do not understand the problem you are having ... please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
    CopyFileRemovingStrayNewlines(@"C:\ext.txt", @"C:\xt2.txt", @"""\""A");
```

With this method:

```
public static void CopyFileRemovingStrayNewlines(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, string linePrefix)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath);
    bool firstLine = true;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(linePrefix))
        {
            if (!firstLine)
                File.AppendAllText(destinationPath, Environment.NewLine);
            else
                firstLine = false;
            File.AppendAllText(destinationPath, line);
        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText(destinationPath, " ");
            File.AppendAllText(destinationPath, line);
        }
    }

}
```

It does have the problem of appending to an existing file, though. I suggest `using` a `StreamWriter` rather than `AppendAllText`. Like this:

```
public static void CopyFileRemovingStrayNewlines(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, string linePrefix)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath);
    bool firstLine = true;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destinationPath, false))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(linePrefix))
            {
                if (!firstLine)
                    writer.WriteLine();
                else
                    firstLine = false;
                writer.Write(line);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(" ");
                writer.Write(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not work. You always write a newline if a line is well-formed (and not the first line). You should only do this if the following line is also well-formed.

Comment: @klausbyskov - Um, no. It is OK to write the line so long as a newline is not also written after it.

Comment: I actually tested this code before posting it, which is why I am the only one whose answer outputs a space character where the extra newline used to be. The test data requires it, and the OP included that part in the sample code, but it's not the focus of the question.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like your string is not well formated...

try this `"\"\\\"A\""` instead

```
public void step1a()  
            {
        string begins = ("\"\\\"A\"");
        string betaFilePath = @"C:\ext.txt";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(betaFilePath);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(begins))
            {
             File.AppendAllText(@"C:\xt2.txt",line);
             File.AppendAllText(@"C:\xt2.txt", "\n");
            }
            else
            {
            string line2 = line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\xt2.txt",line2);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work. It looks like you are putting the new line characters in the wrong place, just as the OP did.

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge: actually you are right... I did saw the problem of da string but did'nt see da appending stuff... my bad

Comment: Umm my problem isnt the finding the if (line.StartsWith(begins)) its the else statement, it appends line2 to a new line

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `\` is a C# escape code.
Your string is parsed as `"A`, because `\"` is the escape code for a single `"`.

You should make the `begins` string an @-string, which does not use escape codes.
You will then need to escape the `"` by doubling it up.
For example:

```
const string begins = @"\""A";
```

Note that the best way to do this is to use a `StreamWriter`, like this:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = File.Create(@"C:\xt2.txt")) 
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(begins))            
            writer.WriteLine();  //Close the previous line

        writer.Write(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SLaks you cannot always use `WriteLine` in the if part. You need to join it with following line if that line does not `StartWith` the constant.

Comment: This will add an extra blank line to the beginning of the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @SLaks's example here is some code that should do the trick:

```
 public static void step1a()
 {
    string betaFilePath = @"C:\ext.txt";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(betaFilePath);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create(@"C:\xt2.txt")))
    {
        string buffer = null;

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (!line.StartsWith(begins))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(buffer + line);
                buffer = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (buffer != null)
                    writer.WriteLine(buffer);
                buffer = line;
            }

        }

        if(buffer != null)
            Console.Out.WriteLine(buffer);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This code will appeand a line with the correct prefix to the end of a line with an incorrect prefix, rather than removing the stray new line character.

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge: Uhm, no I don't think it will.

Comment: It did however forget to print the value of the last line if this was well-formed. I have edited my answer with a fix.